# How do I Remove/301 Trailing Slash for 1 RewriteRule, and Add Trailing Slash on rest of site?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment I have a htaccess rewrite which allows either a trailing slash or no trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^trams/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$ trams/more_details.php?id=$3&tram=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

For this specific rewrite above, I'm trying to change it so that **if** the URL has a trailing slash it 301 redirects to a version *without* a trailing slash, but I'm not sure what to add to the above line?

To complicate matters, there is block of code at the top of the htaccess file that adds a trailing slash to certain URLs throughout the website (this is a requirement for the rest of the website, sorry for the inconsistency), and so I also need to figure out what line I need to add to the block below in order to ignore the above rule....

```
# If requested resource does not exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and does not end with a period followed by a filetype
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
# and does not end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# then add a trailing slash and redirect
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove trailing slash from your given URL pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^(trams/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\d-]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# If requested resource does not exist as a file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# and does not end with a period followed by a filetype 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$ 
# URL is not the one we don't want a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/trams/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\d-]+$ 
# then add a trailing slash and redirect 
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**PS:** Make sure to put this rule on top of all other existing rules.

Comment: Hi, if you could read my question again that would be appreciated :)

Comment: `If the URL has a trailing slash it 301 redirects to a version without a trailing slash` Do you want this to happen to only provided URI pattern in your question?

Comment: hi thanks, yes I only want the trailing slash removed for the URI pattern in my question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit confused, so do I add:  `trams/more_details.php?id=$3&tram=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` after the answer you gave?

Comment: Or `RewriteRule ^(trams/[a-z-]+/[a-z0-9-]+/[0-9-]+)/$ $1 trams/more_details.php?id=$3&tram=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: As I wrote: `Make sure to put this rule on top of all other existing rules.` This additional rule will make an external redirect by removing trailing `/`. Your existing rule is doing an internal forward and should come after my suggested rule.

Comment: Thanks very much, I saw your note, I just didn't realise the reason for it. Great help.

Comment: sorry I just realised that in my htaccess file I hadn't uncommented the 4 lines in the second block of code in the main description. Once I did this I get a redirect loop: `Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`- FYI in my htaccess your line comes first, then the large 8 line block of code, and then my line `RewriteRule ^trams/` etc - any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: If you can post your complete and latest .htaccess in your question I should be able to spot the problem area.